# Visual effect of formulas in mac

Tags: discussion, support, mathjax

[image]

As can be seen, some parts of the formulas overlap with each other in mac. So the visual effect is not really satisfying. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What browser (including version number) and MathJax renderer are you using? You can find the math renderer by control-clicking on a formula, then following the menu "Math Setting" -> "Math Renderer".

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: @KReiser I'm using Google Chrome version 111.0.5563.110 (arm64) and the Math Renderer is HTML-CSS. After change the Math Renderer to Comman HTML, the result looks perfect. Thanks for your hint!